# Leaflet: Polygonmarker instead of circlemarker

Tags: leaflet

I am looking for a way to display a polygonmarker instead of a circlemarker in leaflet.
I am not looking for a way to draw a polygon on the map, because I need it to be the same size independent of zoomlevel.
Drawing a polygon also requires multiple coordinates which I don't have.

example: There is a spot on a mountain that allows to start flying here in winddirections from North to Southwest.
I want to draw a cone in those directions.

Can this be done in leaflet? I've looked around but can't find a solution to this.
If not, any suggestions?

Comment: Can you further explain "...a spot on a mountain that allows to start flying here in winddirections...".  Are you essentially trying to draw an isosceles triangle with the drawn due north and then rotated to match wind direction?  I can see two possible solutions: 1. Calculate and redraw triangle on zoom end (funner solutions), or 2. create a map marker and rotate it (boring solution).  If you setup a JS Fiddle (or equal) I can help you a bit.

Comment: http://turfjs.org/docs#transformRotate

Comment: I am indeed trying to draw an isosceles triangle, but in some cases it can be a narrow triangle, in other cases a broader one. For instance: -North to souteast, -South to Southwest,... But I need to draw a whole lot of them. I fear that if I always recalculate after zoom, it will not be fluent.

Comment: This app has what I want to achieve: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.GliderPal